# Nothing is displayed on the Windows form

Tags: c#

I wrote all the code, I launch the program, but the Windows form is empty. Help me please!
The Windows form starts, but it is empty, although there should be cells. Nothing is displayed on the Windows form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const int mapSize = 8;
        public const int cellSize = 50;

        public int[,] map = new int[mapSize, mapSize];

        public Button[,] buttons = new Button[mapSize, mapSize];


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            ConfigureMapSize();
            InitMap();
            InitButtons();
        }
        
        private void ConfigureMapSize()
        {
            this.Width = mapSize * cellSize + 20;
            this.Height = (mapSize +1) * cellSize;
        }

        private void InitMap()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++)
                {
                    map[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        private void InitButtons()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++)
                {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Location = new Point(j * cellSize, i * cellSize);
                    button.Size = new Size(cellSize, cellSize);
                    this.Controls.Add(button);
                    buttons[i, j] = button;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need to call Init() in the form's Load or Shown event.

Comment: Do you call `Init()` ?

Comment: I removed: "I don't know what to write anymore. I don't know what to write anymore. I don't know what to write anymore" from your question, hope that can agree with that ? 

Comment: please add details about how you instantiate and show the form - without that no one can help

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor and it will work:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Init(); // Add this line
}
```